# Appcelerator Titanium include static library .a in module xcconfig

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I'm trying to include a static library in module.xcconfig. But the documentation isn't helpful, and all the discussion I can find does not give a solution.

Where do I put the static library, and how do I include it using OTHER_LDFLAGS? I've tried:

- OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) mylib.a
- OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -lmylib

mylib.a is in the root of the module at the same level as module.xcconfig, because someone on the Appcelerator site said to do that.

build.py runs fine for the module, but once I try to build my project, I get:

The following build commands failed:
[ERROR]         Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ ... normal i386
[ERROR] (1 failure)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you fix this issue? I got same issue, Please help me to fix

Answer (score 1):

add this line to the module.xcconfig

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework GameKit
```

where GameKit is your missing framework that is used in your library.
And add your library direct to your xCode project via drag-n-drop.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to include the fill path to the library, also it should be included in the build settings of the xcode project